# Minimum / maximum of "sum" with relative values

Tags: mysql

I have the following table `test`:

```
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
|  1 |    -3 |
|  2 |    -5 |
|  3 |    10 |
|  4 |    -1 |
+----+-------+
```

For MIN(value) I get -5, for MAX(value) I get 10, and for SUM(value) I get 1. However, I would like to get the minimum and maximum value when progressing through the table step by step.

Example 1: `SELECT AWESOME_FUNCTION_SUM_MIN(value) FROM test ORDER BY id ASC`

This should return -8 (first row is -3, plus the second row -5 results in the lowest value over the course of all values).

Example 2: `SELECT AWESOME_FUNCTION_SUM_MAX(value) FROM test ORDER BY id ASC`

This should return 2 (first row -3, second -5, and third row +10 leads to the highest value over the course of all values).

Obviously, `ORDER BY` does not really make sense, since it is used for ordering the results of a query, but I used it here anyways for demonstration purposes. To me, this is such a basic functionality, so I was surprised to find nothing about it. I potentially am using the wrong keywords. Can somebody help me out? Or do I have to extract all values and do the analysis externally (=not with MySQL)?

Comment: Can you also post the expected result set?

Answer (score 0):

To get a cumulative sum, you can join a table to itself.

```
select min(val) 
  from (select sum(a.value) as val from test a join test b
    on a.id<=b.id group by b.id) t1;
/* answer: -8 */

select max(val)
  from (select sum(a.value) as val from test a join test b
    on a.id<=b.id group by b.id) t1;
/* answer: 2 */
```

Answer (score 0):

**Create table/insert data.**

```
CREATE TABLE test
    (`id` INT, `value` INT)
;

INSERT INTO test
    (`id`, `value`)
VALUES
    (1, -3),
    (2, -5),
    (3, 10),
    (4, -1)
;
```

MySQL doesnt have those functions but you can simulate them using a self join.

**Query SUM_MIN**

```
SELECT 
 SUM(test.value)
FROM 
 test
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 
   id
  FROM 
   test
  WHERE
   test.value > 0 
  ORDER BY 
   id ASC
  LIMIT 1 
)
 AS 
  positive_number
ON
 test.id < positive_number.id 
ORDER BY 
 test.id
```

**Result**

```
sum(test.value)  
-----------------
-8
```

**Query SUM_MAX**

```
SELECT 
 SUM(test.value)
FROM 
 test
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 
   id
  FROM 
   test
  WHERE
   test.value > 0 
  ORDER BY 
   id ASC
  LIMIT 1 
)
 AS 
  positive_number
ON
 test.id <= positive_number.id  
ORDER BY 
 test.id
```

**Result**

```
sum(test.value)  
-----------------
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
SELECT x.*
     , @least:=LEAST(@least,value) least
     , @greatest:=GREATEST(@greatest,value) greatest
     , @i:=@i+value running 
  FROM my_table x 
     , (SELECT @least:=1000,@greatest:=-1000,@i:=0) vars 
 ORDER 
    BY id;
+----+-------+-------+----------+---------+
| id | value | least | greatest | running |
+----+-------+-------+----------+---------+
|  1 |    -3 |    -3 |       -3 |      -3 |
|  2 |    -5 |    -5 |       -3 |      -8 |
|  3 |    10 |    -5 |       10 |       2 |
|  4 |    -1 |    -5 |       10 |       1 |
+----+-------+-------+----------+---------+
```